# Is there a way of adding promotion information to the basket?

Tags: cart, ce-1.9.0.1, shopping-cart, promotions

I've starting creating various promotions, which are all working fine.

I will be adding information about the special offer to the product listing.
However, I would like to tell the customers about the special offers at the cart stage, which will read the contents of the cart and highlight the appropriate offer/s.
ie: "Buy One More Banana For Only £1"

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't usually promote an extension as an answer but in this case what you're looking for matches the use of the extension exactly.

[Checkout promo extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/checkout-promo-by-aheadworks.html) and [Promo banner extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/promo-banners-by-amasty.html) will do exactly what you are looking for and both are written by module vendors who write decent code and offer (paid) support on their extensions. I've used both on projects before and they work very well.

The idea is you can display text or images in the cart page based on rules just like with a `cart promotion`

Comment: The problem with both of those is that it only allows one promotion to be highlighted - so if there's more than more offer available, they might miss one! What I really want is something that adds text to the product line in the basket

Comment: Hm ok I see the point. In that case these wouldn't work. Since the logic behind these extensions is pretty complex writing out an answer for you would be way to long for an answer and honestly would take a couple of hours to work out and debug. An option might be to contact one of the vendors to see if they do custom work on the extension